# Need Assistance with Vuejs/Veutify (proboblem with input field and deleting items in list)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im busy learning Veujs and I have two Issues.

I'm creating a simple todo app with CRUD functionality and I am passing data through an Input field and it doesn't want to set to full width if I set any rules for it in CSS

Secondly is I have a delete button that shows when you check the checkbox as complete, but I don't know what I am doing wrong I followed the vuejs documentation googled but the button doesn't want to remove the item from my list

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<template>
  <v-card class="wrapper mx-auto">
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title c class="title">Your Todo's</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        clearable
        clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-list-item>
    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-container id="todoApp">
      <v-form name="todo-form" method="post" action v-on:submit.prevent="addTask">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="addTodoInput"
          v-bind:class="{error: hasError}"
          label="What are you working on?"
          solo
          @keydown.enter="create"
        >
          <v-fade-transition v-slot:append></v-fade-transition>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-form>

      <v-divider class="mb-4"></v-divider>
      <v-card class="todo-lists" v-if="lists.length">
        <v-list-item v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id">
          <v-checkbox v-model="list.isComplete" :color="list.isComplete ? 'success' : 'primary'"></v-checkbox>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <input class="input-width" type="text" v-model="list.text" />
          </v-list-item-action>

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-scroll-x-transition>
            <div v-if="list.isComplete">
              <v-btn class="ma-2" v-on:click="removeTask(id)" tile large color="error" icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-trash-can-outline</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-scroll-x-transition>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    addTodoInput: null,
    lists: [
      { id: 1, isComplete: true, text: "go home" },
      { id: 2, isComplete: true, text: "go home" }
    ],

    hasError: false // <-- to handle errors
  }),

  methods: {
    addTask: function() {
      if (!this.addTodoInput) {
        // <--- If no value then we are setting error to `true`
        this.hasError = true;
        return;
      }

      this.hasError = false; // <--- If textbox is filled then setting error to `false`

      this.lists.push({
        id: this.lists.length + 1,
        text: this.addTodoInput,
        isComplete: false
      });
      this.addTodoInput = ""; //clear the input after successful submission
    },
    updateTask: function(e, list) {
      e.preventDefault();
      list.title = e.target.innerText;
      e.target.blur();
    },
    create() {
      console.log("create");
    },
    removeTodo: function(lists) {
      this.todos.splice(list, 1);
    }
  }
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
input.input-width {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right, But you need to remember you variable names, LOL.

Your delete button is calling `removeTask` but in your methods it is renamed as `removeTodo`. In the same method you are trying to splice from data `todos`. But in your data, its renamed as `lists`. Also, you are passing `lists` as an argument but it is then used as `list`

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" v-on:click="removeTask(id)" tile large color="error" icon>
  <v-icon>mdi-trash-can-outline</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

```
removeTodo: function(lists) {
  this.todos.splice(list, 1);
}
```

To get everything work you just need to correct the method to remove todo as below

```
removeTask: function(list) {
 this.lists.splice(list, 1);
}
```

**WIDTH**

You need to set width for v-card, so just update your CSS class as follows.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for styling and making your input full width use `<v-row></v-row>` and `<v-col></v-col>` combination which is important part of Vuetify structure. for example:

```
<v-row align="center" justify="center">
  <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
    <your-input-goes-here/>
  </v-col>
<v-row>
```

use  tag instead of div in showing delete section, using div will affect your styling.

```
<template v-if="list.isComplete"> ... </template>
```

you called `removeTask(id)` function which doesn't exist !
either change it to `removeTodo(list)` or write new function !

```
      <v-scroll-x-transition>
        <template v-if="list.isComplete">
          <v-btn class="ma-2" v-on:click="removeTodo(list)" tile large color="error" icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-trash-can-outline</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template >
      </v-scroll-x-transition>
```